# Obj-C: Image name still being retained on a button despite changing the image from a previous function

Tags: objective-c, image, uiimage

I was hoping you could help me work out why a particular piece of code isn't working how I'd like it to - relating to loading images into different arrays that will populate a grid.

My program has a grid of 16 squares (called button1, button2, etc), each of which will have a picture, which essentially will either be a black picture, a white picture or a green picture (the black/white pictures are the same across all tiles but each individual green tile (of which there are currently 32 that are unique)). When the user selects a different level, which is just through a 'NEXT' or 'PREVIOUS' button on the screen, the idea is that the 16 icons are loaded with the appropriate icons dependant on what was previously saved into the array.

So basically if the icons are labelled 1-16, the next level will be 17-32, etc. When I move from Level 1 to Level 2 I want to save the images currently on the screen into the array I call level1part1, and then to load into the same squares the contents of the array level1part2. When I move back from Level 2 to Level 1 - I want to save the images on the screen into level1part2, and then load the contents of the level1part1 array back to the 16 tiles on the screen.

So initially when the screen is loaded i have the following declarations in the viewDidLoad method:

```
UIImage *def = [UIImage imageNamed:@"silhouette.png"];
level1part1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, nil];
level1part2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, nil];
currentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, def, nil];
```

Where def is the black image. The current array I will explain the use for in a second.

I have two methods, called pressPreviousLevel and pressNextLevel explained below:

```
- (IBAction)pressNextLevel:(UIButton *)sender {

NSMutableArray *nextLevelArray;

if (currentlevel == 1)
{
    nextLevelArray = level1part2.mutableCopy;
    [self.nextLevel setHidden:YES];
}
```

I declare an NSMutableArray called nextLevelArray that will hold the contents of the images I want to project onto the next screen - in this case level1part2 as I am going from level1 to level2.

```
//// SAVING IMAGES ON SCREEN TO CURRENTARRAY
[currentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject: button1.imageView.image];
[currentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject: button2.imageView.image];
[currentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject: button3.imageView.image];
[currentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject: button4.imageView.image];
```

etc

I then populate the currentArray array I declared earlier with what is on the screen currently.

```
if (currentlevel == 1)
{
    level1part1 = currentArray.mutableCopy;
}
```

and then I say that as I am on level 1 - I want to have that level1part1 is equal to this currentArray; effectively saving what is on screen to this level1part1 array.

Now I want to load what is in level1part2 onto the 16 tiles on the screen:

```
// REPLACE IMAGES WITH PREVIOUS LEVELS IMAGES FROM ARRAY 
button1.imageView.image = [nextLevelArray objectAtIndex:0];
button2.imageView.image = [nextLevelArray objectAtIndex:1];
button3.imageView.image = [nextLevelArray objectAtIndex:2];
button4.imageView.image = [nextLevelArray objectAtIndex:3];
```

etc

```
currentlevel ++;
```

and augment the current level.

The similar happens for pressPreviousLevel:

```
- (IBAction)pressPreviousLevel:(UIButton *)sender {

NSMutableArray *previousLevelArray;

if (currentlevel == 2)
{
    previousLevelArray = level1part1.mutableCopy;
    [self.previousLevel setHidden:YES];
    [self.nextLevel setHidden:NO];
}

/// SAVING IMAGES ON SCREEN TO CURRENTARRAY
[currentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject: button1.imageView.image];
[currentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject: button2.imageView.image];
[currentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject: button3.imageView.image];
[currentArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject: button4.imageView.image];
```

etc for the remaining tiles. So if I am currently on Level 2 (can't be on level 1 as I can't go backwards from there) I declare a NSMutableArray called previousLevelArray that will hold the contents of in this case level1part1. I then save all the 16 images that I see on the screen to my currentArray.

```
if (currentlevel == 2)
{
    level1part2 = currentArray.mutableCopy;
}
```

Now, I ask what level I am currently on and save the currentArray which should have all my icons from the screen in order to the correct array - in this case it should be level1part2.

```
// REPLACE IMAGES WITH PREVIOUS LEVELS IMAGES FROM ARRAY
button1.imageView.image = [previousLevelArray objectAtIndex:0];
button2.imageView.image = [previousLevelArray objectAtIndex:1];
button3.imageView.image = [previousLevelArray objectAtIndex:2];
button4.imageView.image = [previousLevelArray objectAtIndex:3];
```

etc

```
currentlevel --;
```

Finally, I now load back my images from the previousLevelArray (in this case level1part1) onto the screen.

So, my problem is this - Let's say my first icon on Level 1 is a green one (let's call it GREEN1) - which is unique to that tile for that level - when I press next, my screen is populated with black icons, which is what I am wanting. When I click on the first icon again in this next level however, it changes to the GREEN1 icon, which is not want I want - it's somehow still being retained - and this is spoiling my program. The same happens if I do the opposite - going from Level 2 to Level 1 - the first icon on Level 1 will turn into the first icon on Level 2.

There's nothing in my method when you click the icon that will change the picture, so I am confident the issue is in this code. Basically it's showing the correct icons on the screen, but when I click on the icon - it's still retaining some of the information from the previous screen - as if it has not finished loading or something.

So my question is, can anybody spot something that's happening in the code that might lead to this problem? I am certain the problem doesn't lie elsewhere in the code - and it is a simple fix on the code I printed above to get this working properly.

Thanks in advance for your help - and if there is any 'bad code' in here, please let me know - always willing to learn - I have only been working with Objective C for a short period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-setImage:forState:` or `-setBackgroundImage:forState:` to set the button's image.

You can set different images for different control states, such as UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted, and UIControlStateSelected.

Comment: Of course! You are indeed right, I have applied that change and it has worked perfectly. Thank you so much Darren, you have saved me hours of headaches and I understand completely why that now works! So grateful for this site and the people who help answer the questions!